# What does the expression mean(^bus === 1'bX) in verilog?

Tags: verilog

I was finding a way to detect any x or z present in input so I find out this (^bus === 1'bX) but I am unable to interpret it. How are we able to detect x or z using this expression and with whom are we doing the xor of bus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left side `^bus` is [unary reduction xor operator](https://www.asic-world.com/verilog/operators2.html). For example, if `bus` is three bits wide, `^bus` is equivalent to `bus[0] ^ bus[1] ^ bus[2]`. If any of the bits is `X` or `Z`, it is propagated to the result.

The right side `1'bX` is a [1-bit wide literal](https://www.asic-world.com/systemverilog/literal_values1.html) that has all bits set to `X`.

The operator `===` compares the sides, including equality of `X` and `Z` states.